# Proving $f(n + 1) > f(n)$ and is f injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

If I have a function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ defined for every $n \in \mathbb N$  by:
$$f(n) = (n+1)!-1$$

How would I prove that $f(n+1) > f(n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Would it be sufficient to show that $f(n+1) > f(n)$ is true for the lowest element that n can be?
And how would I prove that f is indeed injective?

Comment: Compare f(n) and f(n+1) by writing them side by side.The inequality should follow.

Comment: You'd need to show $f(n+1)>f(n)$ true for all $n$ (not just some initial values). Note that on subtraction $f(n+1)-f(n)$ the extra $-1$ in the formula cancels and you can factor the rest using factorial definition.

Comment: For the second part,try using the definition of injectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$(n+2)!=(n+2)(n+1)!\ge2(n+1)!>(n+1)!,\quad \forall n\ge0$$
then we see that $f(n+1)>f(n)$ and then $f$ is injective since by definition

$$n\ne m\implies f(n)\ne f(m)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(n+1)! = (n+1)n! > n!, \forall n \geq 1$$

Every strictly increasing function is injective.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $a > b \iff a-b> 0$

$$\begin{align} f(n+1)- f(n) & = [(n+2)! - 1] - [(n+1)! - 1]\\ \\
& = (n+2)! - (n+1)!\\\\
& = (n+1)!(n+2-1) \\ \\
& = (n+1)(n+1)!\gt 0,\; \forall n \in \mathbb N\end{align}$$

Hence, for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $f(n+ 1) \gt f(n)$

The function is strictly increasing, hence must be injective.

Indeed for two distinct natural numbers $m, n,$:

$\; m \neq n \implies m > n$ or $n> m$

$\implies f(m)\gt f(n)$ or $f(n)> f(m)$ respectively,

$\implies f(m) \neq f(n).$